# Angular trys to ajax templates whilst using $templateCache

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, gulp

I am using `gulp (html2js)` to compile all of my html into angular's `$templateCache` and `browserify` to then include the files I want.

However I am new to `angular` and it doesn't seem right to me that when I use the `$templateCache` `angular` would still try to ajax in the templates.

```
 //views.min.js - This has exported correctly as far as I can tell
 !function(e){try{e=angular.module("Views")}catch(t){e=angular.module("Views",[])}e.run(["$templateCache",function(e){e.put("sliderHome.html",'<div class="slider royalSlider rsDefault"><div ng-repeat="item in sliderItems"><h1>{{item.title}}</h1><p>{{item.text}}</p><img ng-src="/img/news/{{item.number}}.jpg"></div></div>')}])}(),function(e){try{e=angular.module("Views")}catch(t){e=angular.module("Views",[])}e.run(["$templateCache",function(e){e.put("results/resultsGrid.html","<div>Results List as is the best</div>")}])}();
```

The above file is included using `browserify` I can see it at the bottom of the file where it should.

**app.js - Angular**

```
app.directive('sliderDirect', function($timeout, $templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: $templateCache.get('sliderHome.html')
        ....
    }
});
```

**Error given**
`GET http://localhost:3001/%3Cdiv%20class=%22slider%20royalSlider%20rsDefault%22…0ng-src=%22/img/news/%7B%7Bitem.number%7D%7D.jpg%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3C/div%3E 404 (Not Found)`

[image]

So why can't I use the `$templateCache` without it trying to ajax it in and as you would expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `template` not `templateUrl`:

```
template: $templateCache.get('sliderHome.html')
```

Comment: Genius... Where abouts is this in the docs? I assume I missed it completely :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templatenamespace-).